# LINQPad: "BadImageFormatException" when using (.NET4) VS2010 assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, linqpad

Using LINQPad, I am trying to test a few snippets with my own C# objects, which are written in .NET 4.0 (Beta 1) using VS2010 B1. When I try to use it, I get the following message in LINQPad:

> BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:...\XX.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233304/using-linqpad-as-primary-query-tool), one of the LINQPad authors mentions that ".. There's already a Framework 4.0 build ..". Anyone knows where is it, or how to get it?

I was also looking for the manifest file for the LINQPad.exe, since I know there is a way to extend support for .NET 4.0 by adding that as a supported version in the manifest file. I once did that, but I can't find out now how to do it !! Anyone knows a reference? Not to mention, I don't know if that would work for LINQPad, and if the manifest file is embedded (since I can't see one).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the beta [LinqPad .NET 4.0 build here](http://www.linqpad.net/Beta.aspx)

Comment: Thanks - seems like I overlook that section of the website.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it can be found here: http://www.linqpad.net/Beta.aspx